# Are all Mongoose Model methods promise based?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I've just started working with Mongoose, and i must say i'm a bit confused: When looking at the Model API documentation, it seems that some methods are callback-based(for example deleteOne), and some return a promise.

To my surprise, it seems that even those methods that do not say anything about returning a promise- actually do return one. For example, this code works, and "query" gets the anticipated object:

```
 const query =  await  this.model.deleteOne({ _id:id  })
```

Even though in the documentation the example is written like this:

```
Character.deleteOne({ name: 'Eddard Stark' }, function (err) {});
```

Am i missing something about Mongoose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically most operations on models are queries. From the [docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html#queries-are-not-promises)

> Mongoose queries are not promises. They have a .then() function for co and async/await as a convenience. However, unlike promises, calling a query's .then() can execute the query multiple times.

So you can use the methods either way, with a callback function or as a promise.

Comment: This is interesting...i need to inquire this :D Thank you.

Comment: Just one more important question: If this isn't a promise, what about error handling? With the syntax i used, will i be able to catch an error? Does it throw an exception?

Comment: AFAIK it does throw exceptions. So you can wrap the "promise" version in try/catch.